# JavaScript engine calculations speed

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I need to repeatedly calculate the value of JavaScript function with different parameters from Java code.
I am doing something like this:

```
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine mEngine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        Date s = new Date();
        mEngine.eval(String.format("%f*%f + %f*%f", rnd.nextDouble(),rnd.nextDouble(),rnd.nextDouble(),rnd.nextDouble() ));
        Date e= new Date();
        long time = (e.getTime() - s.getTime());
        System.out.println("calc Time is " + time);
    }
```

As a result calculation time increases in proportion to the number of iterations.
For example, at first iteration calculation Time is 45msec, at 200th - 135 msec, at 400th - 261msec.
What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce using 1.8.0_51.

Comment: Thank you so much! The update has solved the problem.